# How to delay document.location.href redirect via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, location, document, location-href

I am using AJAX to login to Wordpress, which upon successful login redirects the user using `document.location.href`. However, I wish to add a small delay to this redirect so that the user can see for a moment that the login has been successful (which I indicate via the text in the submit button).

I have tried using `setTimeout(function() { document.location.href = newURL }, 3000);` but the delay is being ignored, and redirect occurs immediately. What is the correct way to delay this?

```
// AJAX call
$.ajax({
    ...

    // Form success
    success: function(){

        // Delay redirect
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
        }, 3000);
    }    
});
```

Comment: The timeout should work. The problem is most likely because this logic is running under an event handler which itself is redirecting the page, such as the `submit` of a `form`, or `click` of an `a`. It's that event you need to stop

Comment: Ah, perfect, my e.preventDefault(); was in the wrong place, at the bottom of the click event rather than the top. Thank you! If you'd like to convert to an answer I will accept :)